# Is single cloudera single user mode used in production?

Tags: linux, hadoop, cluster-computing, cloudera, administration

I have set up two cloudera hadoop clusters using default user and single user mode, but I have no idea which is the correct method using in production.

Answer (score 1):

In a conventional Cloudera Manager deployment, the Cloudera Manager Agent, which manages Hadoop processes on each host, runs as the root user. However, some environments restrict access to the root account.

In single user mode, the Cloudera Manager Agent and all the processes run by services managed by Cloudera Manager are started as a single configured user and group. Single user mode prioritizes isolation between Hadoop and the rest of the system over isolation between Hadoop processes running on the system.

I would suggest skip the **single user mode** option.